# How to convert audio byte stream to torch tensor?

Tags: audio, pytorch, tensor, bytestream

I am trying to convert `bytes` audio stream to PyTorch tensor as input to PyTorch's `forward()` function.

(To be more specific, I am using a `Nemo` Speaker model for speaker identification:

`audio_signal, audio_signal_length = torch.tensor([audio]), torch.tensor([audio_length])`
)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I have a very similar question. I am using PyAudio to record audio in real time, store the audio frames in memory as IOByte object and would like to convert these frames into torch tensor. Have you found any solutions in the mean time?

Answer (score 1):

You may also convert it directly from the numpy array:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np

def audio_to_tensor(audio_frame: bytes):
    buffer = np.frombuffer(audio_frame, dtype=np.int16).astype(np.float32) / 32767.0
    return torch.from_numpy(buffer)
```

It returns a normalized float32 tensor.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me though I am sure there's an easier way

```
import io
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import torch
import torchaudio


SAMPLE_RATE = 16000

def bytes_to_audio_tensor(audio_bytes:bytes) -> torch.Tensor:
    bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
    raw_data = np.frombuffer(
        buffer=audio_bytes, dtype=np.int32
    )
    sc.io.wavfile.write(bytes_io, SAMPLE_RATE, raw_data)
    audio, _ = torchaudio.load(bytes_io)
    return audio.squeeze(0)
```